# Boost Dynamic Linking

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, boost-log

I am aware this question was asked many times before, always ending with the same answer... add `-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK` to your `CMakeLists.txt` file.

However, I've had this in my cmake for a long time and everything was linking without any problems. Now I decided to switch to Ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04 and update my projects one by one....

This is my cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(FOO)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system timer filesystem log program_options unit_test_framework)
find_package(CGAL COMPONENTS Core)
find_library(OPEN_MESH_CORE_LIBRARY OpenMeshCore /usr/local/lib/OpenMesh REQUIRED)
find_library(YAML_CPP_LIBRARY yaml-cpp  REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(JSONCPP jsoncpp)
link_libraries(${JSONCPP_LIBRARIES})
include_directories(${JSONCPP_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -ffast-math -fopenmp -msse2 -march=native -W -Wall -std=c++11")
add_definitions(-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK=1)
add_definitions(-DUNIT_TEST_DATA="${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/data")

include( ${CGAL_USE_FILE} )
include( CGAL_CreateSingleSourceCGALProgram )

set(SOURCE_FILES 
        Foo1.cpp
        Foo2.cpp
        Foo3.cpp)

add_executable(FOO main.cpp ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_include_directories(FOO PRIVATE ${JsonCpp_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(FOO ${OPEN_MESH_CORE_LIBRARY} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${YAML_CPP_LIBRARY} ${JSONCPP_LIBRARIES})

add_library(foo SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(foo ${OPEN_MESH_CORE_LIBRARY} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${YAML_CPP_LIBRARY} ${JSONCPP_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(tests test.cpp ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_include_directories(FOO PRIVATE ${JsonCpp_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(tests ${OPEN_MESH_CORE_LIBRARY} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${YAML_CPP_LIBRARY} ${JSONCPP_LIBRARIES})
```

When compiled, it fails with known long list of problems, all related ending with a message

```
undefined reference to boost::log::v2_mt_posix::...
```

I am not a cmake ninja and it is very likely that I am doing something wrong, however, I can not find out what it is.

**EDIT:**

- I have *successfully* tried to build it on a clean Ubuntu 16.04 with gcc 5 and boost 1.58
- I have *unsuccessfully* tried to build it on a clean 18.04 with gcc7.1
  and boost 1.65
- I have *unsuccessfully* tried to build it on a clean 18.04 with gcc 5.5
  and self compiled boost 1.58
- I have *unsuccessfully* tried to build it on a clean 18.04 with gcc 5.5
  and self compiled boost 1.65

All attempts followed an exactly the same procedure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638539/boost-not-linking-properly-using-cmake-on-ubuntu/29639148

Answer (score 0):

Cause of this problem wasn't in Boost or CMakeLists.txt. It was actually a problem of CGAL calling `find_package(Boost)` again somewhere in their use protocol when `include( ${CGAL_USE_FILE} )` was invoked, and ended up overriding `Boost_LIBRARIES` with links to it's own components, completely omitting what I've found previously.
Here is the [reported issue](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues/3554)

Solution is somewhat dirty as I'didn't patch CGAL up. All it took was changing the order when i call `include( ${CGAL_USE_FILE} )` and placing it at the top.

```
find_package(CGAL COMPONENTS Core)
include( ${CGAL_USE_FILE} )
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system timer filesystem log 
program_options unit_test_framework)
```

Please *NOTE* that this is a quick fix and can result in further problems such as overriding Boost components required by CGAL!